# How to add multiple the_content or something like that?

Tags: the-content

ok...

let me explain:

i have an example post in wp admin

and i want to add :

- some text (already added via the posts editor)
- some custom stuff (some taxonomy that i have already added)
- some videos
- and some images

How can i do this?

I don't know how to add the videos and images after the content (the text )

Comment: Do you want to upload videos and images from your computer or add them from some external resource?

Comment: the videos will be from youtube and the images local

Comment: Is there a reason you can't add these images and/or videos into the post content, the editor already provides a good UI for adding media items, and the built-in oembed support works for the big players like YouTube and Vimeo, amongst others..

Comment: well... the only thing is their display order

Comment: Videos will display in the order the URLs are input into the content. For images, use the WP gallery feature and fill in the order fields that appear(these set the order) with numeric values, lowest will show first, higher later...

Answer (score 1):

so you can do that with the use of custom fields, you can use custom fields, to add images and videos check this [answer](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordbook-add-custom-field-video-to-facebook) it might help you

Comment: I've added some explanations

Comment: @m3tsys check my answer

Comment: i've added the video as custom field :) thank you.

Comment: but what can i do with the images? I want to be like a small gallery of 5-6 images

Comment: for images check this link

http://justintadlock.com/archives/2007/10/27/wordpress-custom-fields-adding-images-to-posts

if you want plugin then this might help you

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-images/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete tutorial with source files that do exactly what you want,
You can upload multi images by cloning the input field and also you can preview, delete images with ajax, add multi metaboxes to multiple/different post types and more.

http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/howto-meta-box-wordpress.html